# Android Accessibility - How to set which control is focused next?

Tags: android, accessibility

Google's official docs say that I should be able to use nxtFocusDown/nextFocusRight to specify this but it is having no effect.
I have set it through xml and code but the scroll ordering still selects the control last.

Comment: Post some actual code dude.

Comment: 'animatedHeader.setNextFocusRightId(R.id.fav_circle);
            animatedHeader.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.fav_circle);
            animatedHeader.setNextFocusForwardId(R.id.fav_circle);
            animatedHeader.setNextFocusLeftId(R.id.fav_circle);
            animatedHeader.setNextFocusUpId(R.id.fav_circle);'

after I'm on animated header control, it skips fav_circle, scrolls all the other controls and then does fav_circle last

Comment: Input focus order doesn't affect accessibility focus traversal order. You would need to use accessibilityTraversalBefore/After. See the top solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729909/modify-accessibility-focus-order

Comment: That's not what Google docs say: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html#focus-order.
TraversalBefore/After does not work on API 4.4.

Comment: It is also linked to here: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2012/04/accessibility-are-you-serving-all-your.html

"In a few cases, you may need to make UI components focusable or change the focus order to be more logical."

Comment: When you say "scroll ordering" do you mean via accessibility traversal (e.g. swipe gesture) or keyboard (e.g. input focus) traversal?

Comment: Accessibility swipe gesture.

Comment: The "Enabling Focus Navigation" section of the page you linked refers only to input (e.g. keyboard) focus. The swipe gestures moves accessibility focus, which is a separate concept that was introduced in API 16. There is no way to control accessibility focus traversal order prior to API 22.

Comment: So if I want to support older devices I am forced to accepting the fact that it will read my UI out of order? Nothing can be done here?

Comment: @Mr_E: Yes. Early versions of talkback always announced in the top-down order that items appeared on screen, and there was no way to force it to do anything else.

Comment: @MooingDuck. Doesn't seem to be the case anymore. It seems there is a compat class for it: [AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.html). It contains methods `setTraversalBefore` and `setTraversalAfter` which appear to have been added in support library 24.1.0.

Comment: @user3829751 I tried to use AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat with ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(myFirstView, new AccessibilityDelegateCompat() { ... }); the AccessibilityDelegateCompat overrides the method onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo where I set the traversal order for myFirstView using AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat; but it doesn't work for API < 22

Comment: Bummer. Thought it was worth a shot. I guess we either need to design our UI hierarchy to match Accessibility hierarchy, or place a bunch of dummy views everywhere for accessibility users.